# vba execute exe command line with 2 parameters

Tags: vba, cmd

I want to run an exe file from VBA with 2 parameters.
To be more specific here is the exact line that works for me in command line (Win+R), I just need it in VBA:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MacroRecorder\MacroRecorder.exe "E:\test.mcr" /a

I tried so far:

```
Sub open_test_file()

Call Shell("C:\Program Files(x86)\MacroRecorder\MacroRecorder.exe 'E:\test.mcr' /a")

End Sub
```

And this:

```
Public Sub StartExeWithArgument()
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String
    Dim strArgument2 As String

    strProgramName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MacroRecorder\MacroRecorder.exe"
    strArgument = "E:\test.mcr"
    strArgument2 = " /a"

    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & strArgument2 & """", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you have thus far?

Comment: I'll edit what i tried so far to the original question

Answer (score 1):

```
Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\MacroRecorder\MacroRecorder.exe 'E:\test.mcr' /a"
```

Note speech marks and quotes

Comment: it says File not found, 

Call Shell("C:\Program Files(x86)\MacroRecorder\MacroRecorder.exe 'E:\test.mcr' /a")